# Не работает :last-child

Tags: html, css

не могу понять,почему не работает :last-child.

Есть footer,для удобства выделил все границами.В footer'e блок иконок(выделил красным)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого блока прописал стили,где присутствует :last-child,с которым у меня проблемы.

**Проблема заключается в том,что отступ справа(у последней иконки) не пропадает!**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот этот кусок в HTML:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точно также уже делал в блоке главного контента.Все прекрасно работало!Подскажите пожалуйста,в чем может быть проблема?Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Иконки в футере, вероятно, обернуты в другие элементы.